# In the context of Azure Websites, is a 2 "small" standard instance setup better than 1 "medium" server instance setup?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I read a lot about the importance of having at least 2 websites instances in Azure, one reason being that MS will only honour it SLA, if there is, due to being able to patch one server while having the other available.

However we current have strict budgets, and currently have 1 medium server with the bigger RAM. I have always believed that bigger server with more RAM is always better. Also 2 cores on the same machine may be quicker as well.

We have noticed the odd recycle, but it is too early to say whether this is due to MS patching.

Assume my application is a MVC3/EF5/SQL Azure app with 10 user concurrency, and processing is straigtforward, ie simple DB queries etc.

In the context of Windows Azure, assuming a budget limit, would 1 medium(2 x 1.6Ghz cores and 3.5 GB RAM) server be better than 2 small(1 x 1.6GHz Core and 1.75GB RAM) web server instances.

Thanks.

EDIT 1

I noticed this question has attracted 2 votes for being opinion based. The question is designed to attract reports from real experience in this area, which of course informs opinion. This is hugely valuable for my work, as also others.

EDIT 2

Interesting about SLA. I was concerned about when MS does an update, then one instance would disappear while this occurred. So what would happen in this case? Does Azure just clone up another instance? Also what happens in situations where one instance is working on a slower process, it might be waiting for something like a DB transaction. With 2 instance the LB would redirect to instance 2. Logically this sounds superior. It will still work with session vars as MS has implemented "sticky sessions".

I am intrigued that you recommend going with a "small" instance. 1.75GB RAM seems so tiny for a server, and 1 core at 1.6GHz. Need to do some memory monitoring here. Out of interest, how many times would the main application dlls load into RAM, is it just the once regardless of numbers of users? May be a basic question, but just wanted to check. Makes you think when one's laptop is 16GB and 8 cores (i7). However I quess there is a lot of different bloating processes going on a laptop, rather than many fewer and small processes on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your app is particularly memory hungry, I would go for a single small and configure the autoscale to start more servers as needed. Then just keep an eye on the stats. You can have a look at how much memory you are currently using; if it's less than what you get with a small instance you don't get any benefit from the extra RAM.

The SLA for Websites does not require two instances, that rule applies only to Cloud Services.

I have found that you can do a  surprisingly large amount of work on single, small instances; I have several systems in that kind of setup which only use a few pct of capacity, even at hundreds of requests per minute. With 10 users you are unlikely to even have IIS use more than one thread, unless you have some very slow responses (I'm assuming you are not using async) so the second core will be idle.
For another example, look at Troy Hunts detailed blog about haveibeenpwned.com which runs on small instances.

Comment: Good answer; if I had to add anything, I would just note that some apps benefit from the multi-virtual core abilities of the larger SKUs like Medium, but each app will be different.

Comment: Thanks for the full answer. I have put my reply as a new EDIT.

Comment: @JeffWilcox, Thank you for this. Would comment hold true for an MVC3/EF5/SQL Azure app? Could different requests make use of both cores, so offering a parallel resource?

Comment: @SamJolly I will see if I can elucidate in the answer more later. But, in short, most web apps spent most of their time waiting for external resources, like DB and network, so are not CPU bound. Similarly, most of the time you don't use much much memory unless you do gargantuan data manipulation in memory or have bad code. Best thing to do is spin it up and look at the stats. As I said, I have systems with many hundreds of request per minute that are sat at <5% CPU on a Small and pretty low memory too. Just spin it up and measure it - it's dead easy to change size.

Comment: @Frans, Thanks for this.... Look forward to your extended answer. You are sharing some most useful experience.